# Updating NSCollectionView from another thread causes it blank

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nscollectionview

There is a NSCollectionView in my Mac application, and it contains some icons. Meanwhile, I am using NSOperationQueue as a task scheduler to queue some operations. In one NSOperation, I modify the Content of NSCollectionView, the view should update at once when Content changes.

If I update it in the main thread, then it works perfectly well. If I put the same source code at the end of the NSOperation::main(), then the NSCollectionView would be completely blank.

Is this some kind of bug or I do it in the wrong way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All interaction with UI elements must be performed on the main thread.

You can use the [`performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread%3awithObject%3awaitUntilDone%3a) method to help you update UI elements from background threads.